# Open Source Azure API Management Developer Portal setup

Tags: azure-api-management

I am installing the [open source version](https://github.com/Azure/API-Portal) of Azure [API Management Developer portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/apiportal/).

I followed the steps mentioned in the [wiki link](https://github.com/Azure/API-Portal/wiki), excepting the point 3 in the wiki link, as org.enterprise github doesn't have github actions enabled and I don't think they would enable it in the future too, as the org uses Jenkins.

Kindly assist in finding a workaround for step 3 with Jenkins i.e. any reference documentation on how to get it to work or any other options to get similar action to point 3.

Alternative to get open-source Azure API developer portal to work without github actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual commands run as part of the workflow are [here](https://github.com/Azure/API-Portal/blob/main/.github/workflows/publish-on-checkin.yml). You can put these in a script and run it in any CI/CD Platform of choice.

Here are the exact commands for reference

```bash
# Install node dependencies
npm install

# Run publish npm script
npm run publish

# Copy final assets (the following is an example if you are copying it for a nginx docker image as an example)
cp -r ./catalog/dist/website/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```